# Customize Allure Report using pytest-allure-adaptor

Tags: python-2.7, pytest, allure

I want to customize my allure test report using `pytest adaptor`. For e.g adding Environment details on the Overview Page. Changing the Report Name on the Overview screen.

I tried adding the environment details in `conftest.py` as suggested in the documentation, but it do not work for me

```
def pytest_configure(config):
    allure.environment(test_server='testserver', report='My Test Report')
```

I also tried adding `environment.properties` in the allure-report folder but that also didn't work. 
Please let me know if I am doing something wrong here and how can I resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

better late than never,
as said in documentation pytest_configure is

> called after command line options have been parsed and all plugins and
>   initial conftest files been loaded.

each plugin has its own pytest_configure method, and what happens here is that your pytest_configure of you conftest.py is called before the pytest_configure of allure plugin.

An easy fix is to ask your pytest_configure to be executed as late as possible (preferable the last one) by adding *@pytest.hookimpl(trylast=True)* as header.

```
@pytest.hookimpl(trylast=True)
def pytest_configure(config):
    allure.environment(test_server='testserver', report='My Test Report')
```

Answer (score 1):

As I discovered in the code realization of `allure` setting environment variables is not implemented yet in the framework for Python.
`allure.py` module.

```
from allure_commons._allure import label
from allure_commons._allure import severity
from allure_commons._allure import tag
from allure_commons._allure import epic, feature, story
from allure_commons._allure import link
from allure_commons._allure import issue, testcase
from allure_commons._allure import Dynamic as dynamic
from allure_commons._allure import step
from allure_commons._allure import attach
from allure_commons.types import Severity as severity_level
from allure_commons.types import AttachmentType as attachment_type


__all__ = [
    'label',
    'severity',
    'tag',
    'epic'
    'feature',
    'story',

    'link',
    'issue',
    'testcase',

    'step'

    'dynamic'

    'severity_level',

    'attach',
    'attachment_type'
]
```

The developers of Allure are aware of that and are working on it.
You can see the respective [bug](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-python/issues/96).

Answer (score 1):

You could set allure test environment data like this:

```
def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):

    session.config.allure.environment(test_server='testserver', report='My Test Report')
```

Old allure pytest plugin is deprecated and new allure pytest plugin is not feature compatible with old one.

If you want to add environment properties, you will have to create `environment.properties` file and place it in alluredir folder.

```
def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    report_dir = session.config.option.allure_report_dir # Gets the --alluredir directory path
    env_details = """a:b
                 c:d
              """

    if report_dir:
        with open('{}/{}'.format(report_dir, 'environment.properties'), 'w') as allure_env:
            allure_env.write({}.format(env_details))
```

This code will create `environment.properties` file and put it in allure results dir. When you serve that directory with allure-cli, you will see environment details.

Answer (score -2):

I never tried pytest adapter. But you convert XML report to HTML with the same tool whatever adapter is. So environment.properties should work. You can test it with https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-testng-example:

1. mvn test
2. create target/allure-results/environment.properties "testserver=My Test Report"
3. mvn site
4. open target/site/allure-maven-plugin/index.html in FireFox
   [image]

If it doesn't, please check Allure version right in HTML report.
[image]