# How to rename pytest Allure report title

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest, allure

I'm using pytest framework for my automation efforts with allure for reporting. I'd like to change the `Title` in the report from `Allure Report` to `test report`. Also, I'd like to change the `allure logo`. Is it possible to change the title and logo ? [image]

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48709263/how-to-customize-allure-report-title-and-logo

Comment: I looked at it already. ```Edit SummaryPlugin.Java file with any text editor

Search for setReportName("Allure Report"); and change to whatever name you want to give. Example setReportName("Automation Report")and save that file```

Comment: I'm using ```pytest-allure``` and I couldn't find the ```summaryPlugin.py``` or equivalent

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35264335/customize-allure-report-using-pytest-allure-adaptor this is for pytest-allure